# Is there any way to do operation with data with blank space without converting them to "NA"?

Tags: r

I have the following dataset?

```
mydata<- data.frame( value = c (1,0,1,"",1,1) )
```

and I wish to calculate the average of these dataset by ignoring blank space:

```
mean(mydata$value, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Check `str` of your data before you do arithmetics. Ensure they are numeric. Also, maybe you could avoid `""` while reading in your data, see `?read.table`, and set `na.strings = c("", "NA")`.

Comment: Just for you to understand - why you can't do this. `""` is regarded as empty character vector, hence converting the whole vector into character vector. What's even more interesting - `data.frame` then proceeds to converting this vector into factor. One option is to revert the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the 'value' column is `factor`, convert it to `character` and then to `numeric` (which automatically converts all non-numeric elements to NA), get the `mean` by specifying the `na.rm` argument

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(mydata$value)), na.rm = TRUE)
```